# PHP & uClassify strange bug

Tags: php, classification

I have a php script that has the code below

```
require_once("uClassify.php");

$name = $_POST['name'];

$uclassify = new uClassify();

// Set these values here
$uclassify->setReadApiKey('my-read-key');
$uclassify->setWriteApiKey('my-write-key');

$text=str_replace(" ", "+", $name);

$google_url = "http://uclassify.com/browse/uClassify/Sentiment/ClassifyText?readkey=My-Read-Key&text=".$text."&version=1.01";

$result = file_get_contents($google_url);

$resp = $uclassify->classify('Understanding if a text is positive or negative is easy for humans, but a lot harder for computers. We can “read between the lines”, get jokes and identify irony. Computers aren’t quite there yet but the gap is quickly closing in.', 'Sentiment', 'uClassify');


print_r($resp);
```

when i run it using console i get the response below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => Classify2414835871331563718
            [classification] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => negative
                            [p] => 0.0650294
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => positive
                            [p] => 0.934971
                        )

                )

            [text] => Understanding if a text is positive or negative is easy for humans, but a lot harder for computers. We can “read between the lines”, get jokes and identify irony. Computers aren’t quite there yet but the gap is quickly closing in.
        )

)
```

ok so far, but when i try to use it in my page using a form and getting the answer in the same page nothing appears. If i comment the line

```
$resp = $uclassify->classify('Understanding if a text is positive or negative is easy for humans, but a lot harder for computers. We can “read between the lines”, get jokes and identify irony. Computers aren’t quite there yet but the gap is quickly closing in.', 'Sentiment', 'uClassify');
```

and echo something everything works just fine again.

here is the script in my html file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#convert').click(function(){
                var name = $('#name').val();    

                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "examplet.php",
                data: {
                    "name": name
                },
                success: function(data){
                $('#results').show();

                $('#results').html(data);
                if(data == 'Η καταχώρηση έγινε επιτυχώς, ευχαριστούμε!'){
                    $('#name').val('');
                }

            }
         });

        });
        });     
</script>
```

Comment: `$_POST['name'];` in console? I wonder how you do that.

Comment: that was commented in console i just posted it to show you my whole code

Comment: What do your apache logs say?

Comment: how can i get apache logs i'm working localhost using mamp

Comment: Is your console using the same PHP installation (and version) as MAMP?  Also, there appears to be a single quote in the first string to classify - is this the same single quote character used to delimit the string?

Comment: ok removed the double quotes and the single one to test it but still no luck also yeah i have the same php version.

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do, but maybe you should use urlencode instead of str_replace.. make sure you send the characters the right way as it seems that you are using Greek letters

Comment: ok i'll check this out too but i don't think that has to do anything with that stuck in the $resp and doesn't go any further unless i comment that line then everything just prints ok

Comment: no has nothing to do with that